# Is there a way to make field level data classification required before creating a new custom field?

Tags: security, metadata

End user has stringent policies on data classification and controls. Need to have policies and procedures in place to ensure all fields are reviewed, classified and if highly sensitive, encrypted.

**Is there a way to force Admins to be required to select one of the available data classifications before creating a new custom field**?

Right now the new custom field creation flow does not even present the Data Classification Metadata field at time of creation, need to edit the field after creation. Would like to surface these attributes at time of creation and make them required. Ideally, also would like to have some controls that ensure that fields are encrypted if required (using Platform Shield).

Nice to have this control in the front-end, but perhaps could be accomplished after the fact as an audit using Apex with the MetaData API that alerts a super Admin if a field is created or updated without data classification fields populated? Could go one step further and apply defaults in an async process.

Otherwise, must enforce a relatively weak 'admin policy' and some form of manual auditing process.

Comment: Would an Apex test be sufficient?  That is definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apex audit was the work-around I was intending to use, as mentioned in my original question. What I was looking for was something that blocked new field creation without classification being completed. A real time validation on metadata...

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, you cannot put a trigger on FieldDefinition.  However, you can implement a scheduled Apex Test that looks something like this (there are a ton of ways you should improve this code).

```
  @isTest
  static void testAllFieldsHaveMetadata() {

    Test.startTest();
      for (Schema.SObjectType sobjType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
        for (Schema.SObjectField fld : sobjType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
          if (fld.isCustom() && !isFieldFromPackage(fld)) {
              // add to Map<SObjectType, Set<SObjectField>> allCustomFields;
          }
        }
      }
    Test.stopTest();

    // now check data in FieldDefinition
    for (FieldDefinition fldDef : soqlQueryFieldDefinitionsFor(allCustomFields)) {
      assertEquals(fldDef.BusinessOwnerId, null, 'meaningful error message');
      assertEquals(fldDef.BusinessStatus, null, 'meaningful error message');
      assertEquals(fldDef.SecurityClassification, null,  'meaningful error message');
    }
  }
```

The tricky part is finding the EntityDefinitionId from SObjectType, but it looks something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN :entityNames
  AND QualifiedApiName IN :fieldNames
```

The other trick is that FieldDefinition doesn't support `queryMore()` so you have to hack it manually.  You also may choose to filter based on the field's CreatedDate or LastModifiedDate so you keep the query within limits.